# Which private key is used when sftp with a different user account

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

My user account is user1 at local. I am trying to sftp to a remote server using account user2 with `sftp user2@remote` using a private key. Does sftp use the id_rsa in `~user1/.ssh/`? Or `~user2/.ssh/`? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private key from local user on local machine (user1).  Public key of user2@remotehost

Edit for more info - you can also specify which identity file to use when making the connection -

```
ssh -i /path/to/private/key user2@remotehost
```

In this case, whichever user you are on your local machine has to be able to read/access the private key you are referencing.